# How to remove additional window in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I installed ecb on Emacs. And when I start my Emacs. An additional window (the Emacs tutorial) appears at the top of the right side. See the picture below:

[image]

And I activate the ecb in the .emacs file.

```
(setq ecb-activate t)
(setq ecb-auto-activate t)
```

How to remove that additional windows?

Answer (score 3):

Use `C-x 0` while point is in the window to remove it. To stop Emacs displaying the splash screen when it starts, add `(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)` to your initialization file.